# Написание скрипта

Tags: php, синтаксис

Новичок в php, пытаюсь разобраться с данными заданиями:

1) Напишите скрипт, который по введенному числу K, выводит на экран фразу "за окном K голубей", причем согласовывает окончание слова "голубь" с числом K (например, "за окном 1 голубь" или "за окном 4 голубя").

2) Напишите скрипт, определяющий номерной знак автомобиля, если известно что номер записывается тремя цифрами, кратен 2,5 и 7, а также сумма цифр номера равна 12.

Интересует синтаксис, так как опыта нет в написании.

Comment: @Олегgg, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: Книги в помощь, если дело за синтаксисом.


Comment: Опишите на псевдо языке решение, постараюсь подсказать по коммандам))

Answer (score 4):

Правила для российского языка. Пригодятся для первого задания.

```
one   → n mod 10 is 1 and n mod 100 is not 11;
few   → n mod 10 in 2..4 and n mod 100 not in 12..14;
many  → n mod 10 is 0 or n mod 10 in 5..9 or n mod 100 in 11..14;
```

Пример на PHP.

```
function getPluralForm($count)
{
    $mod10 = $count % 10;
    $mod100 = $count % 100;

    switch (true) {
        case ($mod10 == 1 && $mod100 != 11):
            return 'one';        
        case (in_array($mod10, range(2, 4)) && !in_array($mod100, range(12, 14))):
            return 'few';
        case ($mod10 == 0 || in_array($mod10, range(5, 9)) || in_array($mod100, range(11, 14))):
            return 'many';
    }

    throw new Exception; // в этом языке нет других форм
}
```

Тест на PHP.

```
$wordForms = [
    'one' => 'голубь',
    'few' => 'голубя',
    'many' => 'голубей',
];

for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $pluralForm = getPluralForm($i);
    printf("%d %s\n", $i, $wordForms[$pluralForm]);
}
```

Больше информации для разных языков можно найти на странице [Language Plural Rules](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html) от [The Unicode Consortium](http://www.unicode.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Второе выполнил, если кому интересно, то вот

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < 9; $j++) {
        for ($k = 0; $k < 9; $k++) {
            $num = $i * 100 + $j * 10 + $k;
            if ((($num % 2) == 0) and (($num % 5) == 0) and (($num % 7) == 0) and $i + $j + $k == 12) {
                if ($i == 0)
                    echo "номер 0$num ";
                else
                    echo "номер $num
    ";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ужас. подумайте как можно упростить алгоритм. вы решили в лоб, наотмашь. 

- если бы сказали что длина номера 1000, вы бы сделали 1000 вложенных циклов?
- кроме того другие условия тоже надо принимать во внимание, если число делится и на 2 и на 5 одновременно. это что значит? например 8 подходит?

Comment: :)  
можно просто.  

    echo 840;

Answer (score 2):

про 1:

окончание зависит от последней цифры числа $K:

- 1 - голубь
- 2, 3, 4 - голубя
- 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14 - голубей

про 2:

Небольшая шпора.
[switch](http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php)

```
switch - ссылка  ^
for($i = 0; $i <10; $i+=2) // Цикл 0,2,4,6,8. Должно пригодится.
{  }
intval($n); // -  округляет в меньшую сторону(пригодится в разбитии числа на цифры).
break; // - выход из цикла(Если ответ найден, нечего просто так гонять его). 
break $n; // -  выход из циклОВ.
  //например 
  break 2; // - выход из 2 циклов.
```

Comment: 11,12,13,14 голубей....... и цикл не нужен.

Comment: Цикл для 2.

P. S. За голубей спасибо.Исправил..

Answer (score 2):

Вот первое

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['k'])){
    $k = (int)trim($_POST['k']);
    if($k != trim($_POST['k']) or $k == '')
        exit('В поле K не содержит числа');
    echo 'за окном '.$k;
    if($k<5 and $k >0)
        if($k == '1')
            echo ' голобь';
        elseif(in_array($k, array(2,3,4))
            echo ' голубя';
    else
        echo ' голубей';
}else
    echo '<form action="" method="POST"><b> Введите K: <input type="text" placeholder="Введите число" size="10" name="k" /> <input type="submit" value="Отправить" /></form>';
?>
```

Насчет строчки

> elseif(in_array($k, array(2,3,4))

можно просто заменить на else.

Надеюсь, что помог. Удачи

Answer (score 0):

Вторую бы решил как то так, то есть в начале три переменные задающие условия дальше уже логика

```
<?php

$count = 3; //Количество знаков в номере
$krat = array(2,5,7); //Массив кратных чисел
$sum = 12; //Сумма чисел в номере

$maxNum = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++)
{
    $maxNum .= '9';
}

for ($i=0; $i < $maxNum; $i++) { 
    $number = $i;

    while ( strlen((string)$number) < $count ) {
        $number = "0".$number;
    }

    $fragments = str_split($number);

    if (array_sum($fragments) != 12)
    {
        continue;
    }

    $kratTest = true;
    foreach ($krat as $item) {
        if ($number % $item != 0)
        {
            $kratTest = false;
        }
    }

    if ($kratTest == false)
    {
        continue;
    }

    echo "Загаданный номер:" . $number;
    break;
}
```